# How to implement .net library into Navision?

Tags: .net, navision

I want implement [Google Analytics Api v4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AnalyticsReporting.v4/) into Navision (2013). But I have absolutely no clue how to do it.

I know there are several .net variables in Navision.

**But how can I implement external libraries?**

Do I have to build an [Navision Extension Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt600278(v=nav.90).aspx)? Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

If there are already dll's for this api then you can just use them as variables in Nav. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh166527(v=nav.71).aspx

Comment: I would do it in NAV 2015 or 2016 instead. There are way too many limitations re DotNet in the earlier versions of NAV. It will drive you crazy